# Can I distribute Xcode at my company internally through configuration management scripts?

Tags: macos, applications, xcode, development

My company is slower to upgrade our developers' workstations and as such we often lag behind in Mac OS and Xcode versions. As such, developers often have trouble installing and configuring the correct versions for internal development.

I'm wondering if I can legally store specific versions of Xcode in an internal drive and have my configuration scripts vend it to developers so that they always receive the company-approved versions? I've tried diving into forums and Google but maybe I'm not searching the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere I have ever worked in 30 years of IT work it is perfectly fine to place an installer on a local/network drive for in-house installation as long as there are no licensing issues.

And since XCode is free to use for anyone with a compatible Mac, I would think yes, this is fine.

Also macOS Server has (I seem to recall) a caching option which stores software updates on your internal network for the very same thing.

Comment: This is how we do it. Also, we pay for a developer license so we can re-download all the old versions of all the old tools on demand if and when we need them to be re-signed or just didn't store the correct copy. We also use JAMF Pro to package the installers and manage them in our Self Service App Store.